# Moving between localhost and remote server with CodeIgniter

Tags: localhost, codeigniter-2, remote-server, base-url

What's the best way to handle moving between development on localhost to live remote server? I have .htaccess mod_rewrite set, but that's not really a problem, because I haven't included that in my subversion repository so I'm not committing it as the rest of the site. But what about the config.php with the base_url? I need to have this set to localhost for development, but changed to the actual domain when deployed.

It's not a huge problem, but I will always have to remember to change this before each time I deploy, or remember to exclude it from deployment. So I was thinking maybe someone had a smart way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load different configuration files depending on what you have set the `ENVIRONMENT` constant to in `index.php`.  In your case you would create two copies of `config.php`.  In your development copy you would have the base URL set to `localhost` and in the production copy you would have it set to `example.com`.  Depending on what the `ENVIRONMENT` constant was set to, the appropriate configuration file would be loaded.

Look at [Handling Multiple Environments](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/environments.html) and the "Environments" section in the [Config Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html) documentation to see how to do this.